# how to change the results delimiter of a select * from table from within a stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, delimiter

lets say within a MYSQL stored procedure I have as a final statement

```
select * from table;
```

I want the results to be delimited by the pipe "|" symbol, not a comma.
Some of the fields in the results have commas in the data.

Is there a way to change that?

Comment: what DBMS are you using?

Comment: I don't understand the term "delimiter" in the context of a SELECT statement. Are you talking about the `mysql` command-line client?

Comment: @SaggingRufus Ironic?

Comment: I don't understand the problem between the semicolon of the `SELECT` statement with the semicolons of the result data. Can you post an example?.

Comment: all he is trying do is changes the comma (because is getting CVS ouput) to the pipping symbol. There must be a setting in the DBMS for this.

Comment: Use [SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html).

Comment: CSV is at most a guess: his command won't generate it and if he happens to be actually doing it he is using some other undisclosed tool.

Comment: SaggingRuffs is correct. I could do "select field1,"|",field2,"|",field3... from x" but I need to do a "select * from x" with "|" as the delimiter, not a comma. Is there a way to do that in MySQL. Thanks everybody for taking the time to review this question.